# Word in Receipt is in wrong Language

Tags: receipts, localisation

We are doing a contribution campaign for the first time where we allow the contribution to be given as a gift (i.e. honoree).

The honoree profile, either the default or our own, requests Name and Surname. In the receipt these two fields are shown together in the same line with the title "Name" in English and not in our language.

I have tried Word Replacement and it does not work.

The same is happening in the option related to giving the contribution "On Behalf Of Organization". Both in the contribution confirmation page and in the receipt it appears in English and Word Replacement does not work.

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know exactly where are these strings but probably they are not ts'd and this has to be done directly in code. It often happens. maybe this answer to a question I had could help you: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31222/6991